# Selenium Webdriver loop over iframe

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver

I am trying to webscrape an iframe object containing a list of links. The ultimate objective is to perform a series of actions, same for each link, that leads to downloading some data in xls format.

For each of the links in the iframe, I want to automate the following actions:

1. click on the link
2. select from a drop down list the option for getting data since 1999
3. click on the excel download button.

My code works for the first of the links, but I am struggling with automating it to go through all the links in the iframe.

This is the code that works for the first link:

```
#this automates the log in
driver.find_element_by_id('user').send_keys('myusername')
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('mypassword')
driver.find_element_by_xpath('myxpath').click()

#this switches to iframe and clicks on all the links 
driver.switch_to.frame("report-iframe")
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()

#this performs the required actions for the first link(select drop down, select excel download)  
s= Select(driver.find_element_by_id('start-date'))
s.select_by_value('1999-01-01')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-excel-download"]')

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'report-excel-download')))
element.click()
```

I want to automate this process for all the links in the iframe (i.e. for each of the links in iframe, click on the link, select the drop down, click the data download button. Does anyone have any advice in how to do this?

I tried:

```
links=[link.get_attribute('href') for link in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('myxpath')]


for l in links:

    #click the link
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()

    #select all years
    s= Select(driver.find_element_by_id('report-control-date-start'))
    s.select_by_value('1999-01-01')

    #click download
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="report-excel-download"]')
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'report-excel-download')))
    element.click()
```

But this only works for the first link in the iframe, it does not work across all.

Does anyone have any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: switch to each frame and then switch back to default. There are answers detailing this on SO.

Comment: What happen when you click to a link? Redirect you to another page, open popup window?

Comment: when I click on a link it redirects me to another page

Comment: So in your loop you click on a link, which takes you to a new page, and do something there. At what point do you go back to the links page?